# How to use UserPassesTestMixin in generic Updateview

Tags: python, django

views.py:

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name ="profile/profile_view.html"


class ProfileEdit(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name="profile/profile_new.html"

    def test_func(request, user_id):
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        if request.user == user.user:
            return True
        else:
            return HttpResponse("<h1>You will not be able to edit other profiles</h1>")
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', ProfileEdit.as_view(), name='profile_edit')
```

I got this error: **(test_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user_id')**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506827/django-how-to-allow-only-the-owner-of-a-new-post-to-edit-or-delete-the-post)  post addresses the same issue I want to solve. Is it different for class based views?

Comment: Where is `user_id` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: No, where is the value for it coming from? You're querying the User model based on that value, but what is the source of the value?

Comment: the detail view.. i just added it

Comment: You're not being clear about anything here, I'm afraid. You're expecting a user_id value in your test function. Where is that coming from? Is it in the URL?

Comment: yes. from the URL

Comment: did you get the question?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things wrong with this method.

The first is that, like any method, it needs `self` as the first argument.

Secondly, as the error states, the code that calls this view is not expecting to pass `user_id` as a parameter. You should get that value, as you would anywhere else in a class-based view, from `self.kwargs`.

Thirdly, you try to access the `user` attribute of the `user`, but that doesn't exist. You could just compare the user directly, but in fact there is no point in querying the user model at all; you can just compare the ID with the current user's ID.

```
def test_func(self, request):
    if request.user.id == int(self.kwargs['pk']):
        ...
```

However, you should also ask yourself whether any of this is the right thing to be doing. Rather than passing the user id in the URL and then checking it's the same as the logged-in user's id, you could just omit the ID completely and just always access the current user. You would do that by defining `get_object` in the view to return `request.user`; you could then remove the UserPassesTestMixin, the test_func, and the URL parameter.

Comment: I want to user to access the edit view only if it is that user's page else display 404.

Comment: Yes. What in my answer leads you to think I didn't realize that?

Comment: are yu saying this cannot be done by **UserPassesTestMixin**?

Comment: No. Where did I say that? I gave you a solution to your current problem, and additionally suggested a different approach that does not use the mixin.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42301134/how-does-userpassestestmixin-in-django-work[link] can you answer this question?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer i needed.

views.py

```
class ProfileEdit(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name="profile/profile_new.html"

    def test_func(self):
        x = self.request.user.username
        y = self.kwargs['slug']
        if x == y:
            return True
        else:
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
                raise Http404("You are not authenticated to edit this profile")
```

I replaced 'id' with 'slug' i will be using that to edit