# How does UserPassesTestMixin in django work?

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
class ProfileEdit(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name="profile/profile_new.html"

    def test_func(self):
        x = self.request.user.id
        print (x)
        y = self.kwargs['pk']
        print (y)
        a = True
        b = False
        if self.request.user.id == self.kwargs['pk']:
            print (a)
        else:
            print (b)
            return redirect ('/login/')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj1TH.png)

as you can see in the output image the test condition actually satisfies.. but why does it print "False" if it's true.

Comment: If you `print repr(x)` and `print repr(y)`, it is clear that they are different. Printing `type(x)` is also useful for debugging.

Comment: Your `test_func` should return either `True` or `False`, you cannot return a redirect response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user id coming from the user in the request object is an integer, while the `self.kwargs['pk']` is a string unless you do something about it. You'd see the difference if you printed `repr()` of the values because the string would have quotes around it because it's extracted from the url path which itself is a string.

Try casting it with `int()` before comparing like `self.request.user.id == int(self.kwargs['pk'])`. Don't forget to catch `ValueError` if there's a possibility of it not looking like an integer.